# Scrolling issue with Vuetify dialogs during migration from Vue 2 to Vue 3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

I am currently in the process of migrating a Vuetify app from Vue 2 to Vue 3. However, I've come across an issue with dialogs in Vue 3 that prevents scrolling when the screen size is reduced. I'm seeking guidance on how to resolve this problem.

I'm using Vuetify ^3.3.9 in the migration process.

[image]

Comment: [Please do not post text, tables, or error messages as images.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/15261914) Please [edit] your question to include the information as text.